# Is it grammatically correct to use "at" twice in a sentence, referring to a time and a place?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, writing-style, time, toponyms

For instance, over email I often write something along the lines of the following:

> I'll arrive *at* 221B Baker Street *at* 11:45 PM.

Is this grammatically correct? Can any improvements be made from a stylistic standpoint?

Comment: What rule would make it not grammatically correct?  As to style, that would depend on the larger context.

Comment: It may depend on whether the dog barks. *I'll arrive **at** 221B Baker Street **at** 11:45PM **at** the same time as Dr Watson or **at** least that's what he said when I saw him **at** the club.*

Comment: @Deadrat: I take it you'd have mentioned if you were **at** dinner at the club, so I suppose you were out [**on** the razz](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-razzle) again! :)

Comment: In my experience, writers often do more damage to their style and coherence by going through contortions to avoid repeating a preposition that they happen to have used earlier in the sentence than they could possibly have done by simply using the natural preposition choice twice. Remember that in speech people use sentences that contain duplicate prepositions all the time—and the baseline for natural expression is the way people actually talk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually we were **at** the bar **at** ease and just **at** the point of being, er, inebriated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's the point of english.stackexchange.com if you have to research the answer to your question before asking it? English is my first language, so I didn't think it appropriate (or obvious) to post on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: @HotLicks That's what I was asking: I personally dislike the style, but I couldn't find any specific grammatical rules which this construct violates.

Comment: @splicer: Google Books claims 63,800 results for [at the station at](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+the+station+at%22), the vast majority of which will match your context. As deadrat's two comments indicate, it's perfectly possible to chain together prepositional clauses almost indefinitely. Even if they keep using the *same* preposition. I don't know why you *dislike* such constructions, but obviously others have no problem with them, and it's unthinkable that there could be a rule against them. (It would be even more mocked than the one about not splitting an infinitive! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answer says, it's grammatically sound. It's hard not to repeat "at"s here, but if you wanted to you could say something like:

- "I'll *reach* 221B Baker Street at 11:45 AM."
- "I'll *make it to* 221B Baker Street at 11:45 AM."
- "I'll be at 221B Baker Street *by* 11:45 AM."

But none of those are necessarily improvements. Stylistically, I think yours is fine.

Comment: Why did I get downvoted?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but... 13 hours after it was posted, this question is on the verge of being closed as off-topic for lack of research by the poster—an excuse for closing that close-voters often use when a question strikes them as being too simple and having too obvious an answer to merit inclusion on the site. When someone answers such a question, there is a possibility that the question will stick—or at least be harder to delete—so (I suspect) people sometimes downvote the answer to make that outcome less likely and to discourage people from answering similar questions in future. ...

Comment: ...I'm not condoning this practice; I'm just saying that you may be on the receiving end of it in this case. It's also possible, however, that the downvoter felt that your answer lacked reference-work support and was therefore "not useful," or even that the downvoter disagreed with your analysis and conclusion. We can't know for sure because the downvoter hit and ran without explanation.

Comment: @SvenYargs haha thanks. I see that this forum seems to differ from the writing stack most principally in that lots of sources are cited. I'll come up with a quote next time. Thanks again!